# Is it possible to use getRecord with NavigationMixins?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a `datatable` with row actions, one of with is an "Edit" item. I'd like to make so that when a user selects that item in a row, a `standard_recordPage` appears. The user can then edit the record and save it. I got that much working, but the updated data wasn't being shown in the `datatable`.

I've been told that using `getRecord` will make it so that changes to the record are propagated to other components, but haven't figure out how to do this.

The data populating the `datatable` is coming from a wired Apex component feeding into a method:

```js
@wire(getLeads, {
    napFilter: '$napFilter',
    fieldName: '$fieldName',
    sortDirection: '$sortDirection',
    searchTerm: '$searchTerm'
}) leads({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.data = data.map((lead) => {
            const statusColor = lead.Status__c === 'NAP' && !lead.NAP_Confirmed__c
                    ? 'slds-theme_warning'
                    : 'slds-theme_default';
            let taskCount, nextDueDate;
            if (lead.Tasks) {
                taskCount = lead.Tasks.length;
                nextDueDate = lead.Tasks[0].ActivityDate;
            } else {
                taskCount = 0;
            }
            return { ...lead, statusColor, taskCount, nextDueDate };
        });
    } else if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The row action simply uses the `NavigationMixin.Navigate` to display the `standard__recordPage` for editing.

```js
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
        recordId: id,
        objectApiName: 'Lead__c',
        actionName: 'edit',
    },
});
```

I thought that perhaps if I stored the record ID of the selected record in a property with `@api` and use `@wire` on `getRecord`, then use reactive variables, that might work, the theory being that passing a reactive variable to the `NavigationMixin` would allow changes in the edit page to propagate back.

```js
@api recordId;
@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '$recordId',
    fields: '$fields'
}) record;
```

But passing `this.recordId` in the call to the `NavigationMixin` didn't propagate the changes to the `datatable` and passing `'$record.Id'` broke the app.

I can picture how I can do this without the `NavigationMixin` by using a custom component that I configure to show, but the `standard__recordPage` already does what I need except that I have to reload the `datatable` to see the saved changes.

Is what I want possible? Is there a better way to do this? Or should I just go the custom modal dialog route?

Comment: I would suggest using empApi, subscribing to 'Lead' updates (Change Data Capture) and on it you can either manually update row or just do `refreshApex(response)`. Because from what I know there is no native way to listen to results from NavigationMixin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the whole code is hard to fully understand the scenario, but as far as I understood your approach is not correct, as you are wiring the record to a property that is not used by the datatable.

I see a possible solution:

Wire the getRecord for the recordId to a function that search the local leads list for the updated item and override its values programatically.

That should do the trick with the caveat that you would generate 2 server communications: one for the wire initialization each time you select a Lead, and another once the record is updated. The first one is not actually needed by your logic as you already have the lead information.

Anyway, you should avoid updating the row in the first call response as I said it would be useless, and it's some "processing time" you can save.

Something like this (sorry I'm in the smartphone):

```js
@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '$recordId',
    fields: '$fields'
})
updateRow({error, data}) {
    //not sure about the Id property name of your model
    let rowItemIndex = this.data.findIndex(item => item.id === data.id );
    let rowItem = {...this.data[rowItemIndex]};
    rowItem.status = data.status; // or whatever you want
       
    // Change the array item by the new one in a way the array notice it.
    // It depends on if you are using or not the @track annotation.
        
    // If @tracked this should be enough, if not apart from this
    // add the next line 
    this.data.splice(rowItemIndex, 0, rowItem);

    // If not @tracked add this 
    this.data = [...this.data]; // not efficient at all    
}
```

Note: remember I am in the phone, so it could be many errors.

Note2: If you are going to modify the "data" array you should then use a private copy of the array when you reteieve it from your apex method, as for Best Practices, returned data should be treated as immutable. `this._data = [...this.data]` and then you use the shallow copy in your template and logic. (Or change the name of the immutable var and it's easier :P)

Comment: You're right, I don't want to hit the server twice for this, but I might try what you suggest just to see if it'll work and if I actually understand it. But for the final solution I'll probably build my own modal dialog and send the save or cancel events up to the page which can then send an update event to the datatable.